# "fxc.exe: No such file or directory" When Compiling Qt on WSL

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm attempting to build a cross-compiling Qt targeting Windows x64 with WSL as the host. I have succeeded in compiling the base parts of it, but I attempted to build a project to test it, only to find that it required qtdeclarative, which I had skipped as it was causing errors. No matter what I do, it always attempts to use fxc.exe to compile some shaders, and I am not sure if there is a way to circumvent this. I have tried reading the configure options to see if there is some way to skip DirectX-related things, but I have been unable to find anything. My configure was run as follows:

```
configure -opensource -no-compile-examples -platform linux-g++-64 -xplatform win32-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32- -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtwebengine -skip wayland -skip qtandroidextras -skip qttranslations -skip qt3d -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtgraphicaleffects -skip qtcharts -skip qtwebview -skip qtserialbus -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtdeclarative -static -opengl desktop -prefix /usr/local/qt-5.15.2 -confirm-license
```

Does anyone know if there is a way around this, or at least what might be causing what is essentially Linux to be looking for .exe files?

Answer (score 1):

Comment it out at "qtdeclarative/src/plugins/scenegraph/scenegraph.pro":

`# qtConfig(d3d12): SUBDIRS += d3d12`

Obviously it won't work on the target afterwards. Ask the "Qt" people why is it not excluded from cross-builds on unsupported hosts.